# Code Not hitting breakpoint in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a mvc c# web application i am building in vs 2012, I put a breakpoint on the controller but that breakpoint is never hit, i get the results so i know that code is running. whats weird is that it doesnt even give the error "no symbols have been loaded" and make the break point hollow. the break point remains solid. Any ideas whats happening?

Comment: In which mode you are running the program, release or debug?

Comment: We'll probably need to see the code....

Comment: Does the browser's debug console network tab show the request was made?

Comment: One thing to try as well is setting `[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]` on your controller action, because Internet Explorer for example doesn't always serve subsequent requests because of default browser caching.

Comment: @Pricey tried it, still did not hit the breakpoint

Comment: Do you run your application with the VS integrated web server or on a (local) IIS and attach to the w3p process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To debug step-by-step, you must do two things. First you must set the breakpoint, then you must attach the debugger to the process running your code. In this case the process that is running your code will be `w3wp.exe`. If you press CTRL + ALT + P, you'll get to the attach to process window. You won't see w3wp here, but check the two boxes at the bottom of the window to show all processes in all sessions and from all users, and then you'll be able to attach to it. Note that if it still doesn't appear, it's because w3wp hasn't been launched yet, so you need to do a request to your web application to spin it up. After attaching, the break point should be hit if the code matches.

Comment: I am not OutputCacheAttribute

Comment: Are you attaching to the w3wp process with the debugger, or just setting the break point but not attaching?

Comment: just setting the breakpoint, when i got to attach to a process dialog box. i dont see w3wp.exe in list of processes

Comment: Ahh OK, let me update my answer.

Comment: shoot, it hit, wow, but why do you think it was not hitting when i just debug code from vs2012

Comment: If you are running on localhost it normally does hit breakpoints. Sounds like a configuration issue or something if it isn't hitting it locally.

Comment: @MikeCheel any pointers on what it could be?

Comment: @Mike - that depends on whether or not it is being run via Visual Studio's debugging web server or hosted within IIS. It is not a "configuration issue" if it is hosted within IIS, just required an extra step of attaching the debugger.

Comment: I was OutputCacheAttribute once... but then I took an arrow to the knee.

Comment: @DavidH - I debug against my IIS localhost all of the time without having to attach to the worker process.

Comment: Yes, because the "localhost" is not IIS but instead the Visual Studio development/debugging web server. Are you running your application via F5 or the Run command @Mike?

Comment: only yestersday my code was hitting breakpoints when doing f5, now i have to attach to a process to get the break point to hit. arghhh

Comment: @DavidH I have the 'Use Local IIS Web server option selected in Web in project properties and specified a project url. It is definitely going against my IIS install and not the built-in from VS OR IIS Express.

Comment: `What was causing it was.` in my project settings -> web -> server it was set to `Use Visual Studio Devlopemnt Server` when i dd set it to `Use Local IIS Web Server` and project url to https://localhost/ it started working